# How to set the background image for the particular index of the button in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, background, uibutton

I have created buttons dynamically and now I want to set the background for a particular index of the buttons.

Here is my sample snippet:

In the interface file:

```
 UIButton *answerBtn;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *answerBtn;


 for(int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {

  answerBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

 [answerBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(30, x, 260, 40)];

 answerBtn.tag = i; 

 [answerBtn setTitle:[answerList objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 
 [self.view addSubview: answerBtn];

}
```

In my case, I want to set the button background in different methods.

```
-(void) custom Method
{
   if(indexValue == correctIndex) // Values are 2
   {
     // so I want to set the background image for the second button

      [answerBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_correct_answer.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

   }
}
```

But it doesn't set the corresponding index, so how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < [myArray count] ; i++ )
{
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setTag:i];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(30, x, 260, 40)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (IBAction) btnClicked::(id)sender
{
  UIButton *btnTapped=(UIButton *)sender;

for(UIView *btn in  self.view.subviews)
{
    if([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {   
        UIButton *btnComp = (UIButton*)btn; 

        if(btnComp.tag == btnTapped.tag)
            [btnComp setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_correct_answer.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        else 
             [btnComp setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_image.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use **-(void)custom:(id)sender** instead of **-(void)custom**.

In the sender you can have the index of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *answerBtn = (UIButton *)[self objectWihTag:1]
```